# How do I increase the Grease Pencil render quality?

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil

I have various **Grease Pencil** assets - rigged & linked to the scene. And I've noticed that the quality of rendered Grease Pencil objects (detailing of lines, its "cubicity") doesn't change - no matter what amount of samples I use for rendering. Have tried both Eevee & Cycles: 64 samples look the same as 4096 samples. The only thing that helps to achieve smooth and clear lines is rendering in 4K and downscaling the image.

Do GP objects use render samples in common way, like mesh for example (I've noticed that Cycles renders tile by tile depending on samples amount & resolution, and then GP just emerges at once - like it's not being rendered, but just... drawn, added after main render is done)?
If not, how can we affect GP render quality?

Comment: by "cubicity", do you mean aliasing? If so, in the render properties panel, under the GP tab, you can change the anti-aliasing threshold, might help

Comment: Yes, I know about this property, but that is just threshold, so it acts like either anti-aliasing works or doesn’t work at all, with no additional levels of smoothness

Comment: right, i agree and been having the same problem as you. Maybe if you edit your question to refer specifically to the anti-aliasing setting and how to make it work properly, someone might answer it

Answer (score 0):

The solution is enabling *Combined and Z Passes* at *View Layers > Passes*

[image: enabling combined and z passes]