# How to cover Grease Pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil

[image] I have a 3d object and a grease pencil object. In the camera view, the object covers the Grease pencil. This is what I want. [image]however, in the render. The grease pencil just penetrate the object? [image]

Comment: see that warning in the top left of your render? you can do that by going to the View Layer Properties, which in the Properties panel is the 4th tab down

Comment: can you send a picture?

Comment: it's like the picture in this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/262566/168